# Existence of the Sobolev-solution of the equation $- \Delta u + {u^3} = 1$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I have the following problem from my Calculus of Variation class.

**Problem.** *Let $\Omega $ be an open, bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Prove or disprove that there exists $u \in W_0^{1,2}\left( \Omega  \right)$ such that $- \Delta u + {u^3} = 1$ in $\Omega$*.

I started with variational formulation of this equation
$$\int_\Omega  {\nabla u \cdot \nabla v}  + \int_\Omega  {{u^3}v}  = \int_\Omega  v \mbox{ for all }v \in W_0^{1,2}\left( \Omega  \right)$$
but the form on the left-hand side is not linear with respect to $u$. So I can't apply Stampacchia or Lax-Milgram theorem.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I wrote "prove or disprove". In my last exam on this subject, the question is open like this, and I still don't know if this statement is true.

Comment: This is a monotone operator equation. It is uniquely solvable indeed.

Comment: @daw Can you give me some references about this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider the operator $A u=-\Delta$ and $B=u^3$ over 
$V=H_0^1(\Omega)$. If we treat them as operators from 
$V$ into $V'$, then it is well-known that $A$ is a maximal monotone. If we prove that $B$ is demi-continuous and monotone, then $A+B$ is also maximal monotone.
Since $V=H^1_0(\Omega)$ is embedded into $L^6(\Omega)$, then $Bu\in L^2(\Omega)$. The Dominate convergence theorem can imply that
$$
\langle B(u_n-u),w\rangle=\int_\Omega (u^3_n-u^3)(x) w(x)dx\to 0
$$
if $u_n\to u$ in $V$. This implies the demi-continuity.
On the other hand, $\langle (A+B)u,u\rangle\geq \int |\nabla u|^2 dx$. Hence, we have 
$$
\frac{\langle (A+B)u,u\rangle}{\|u\|_V}\to \infty
$$
as $\|u\|_V\to \infty$.
Therefore, the operator $A+B$ is maximal monotone and coercive. Then Minty's Theorem yields that this it is surjective from $V$ onto $V'$. Then the equation admits a unique solution in $V$.